# Update help/on-topic to push Careers onto MSO

Tags: feature-request, jobs, help-center

SO Jobs (formerly Careers) [is now supported on MSO](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/274213) primarily. But the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here still says it's on-topic.

> If your question is about:
>
> ...
>
> - [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com)
>
> ...
>
> … it is welcome here.

That should be fixed to stem the tide of misplaced questions here a bit and reduce argufying. (The tag should also be fixed, and I've suggested an edit; there's not much to do about the thousands of old questions, but oh well.)

Comment: Shouldn't it have its own meta instead?

Comment: @DeerHunter: Honestly? It probably should. But it doesn't, and likely won't for a while. This is just trying to sort things out in the reasonably short term.

Comment: @Deer no, why? It's part of Stack Overflow now. If anything, maybe it should have had its own meta before being merged into Stack Overflow