# Update the help center to indicate Stack Overflow Careers questions are off-topic

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta, help-center, scope

Currently the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page on Meta Stack Exchange says:

> If your question is about:
>
> - [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) (Employers). Questions for [Stack Overflow Jobs](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs) should go to [Stack Overflow Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)
>
> … it is welcome here.

A [recent question about Stack Overflow Careers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300708/cant-post-a-job-on-stack-overflow-careers?noredirect=1) was closed as "This question pertains only to a specific site in the Stack Exchange Network". That close reason has a link to the help center page that says Careers questions are on topic here.

The post [was migrated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356389) to MSO by a Careers customer support member of staff, which implies it should indeed be asked on MSO instead...

Could the help center page be updated to indicate this?

---

Note that [Update help/on-topic to push Careers onto MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274294/307988) seems to be talking about what is now called Jobs, and the help center page *has* since been updated to direct those questions to MSO, but what is now (or was? Isn't it "Talent" now?) called Careers (confusing right?) is still apparently on-topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Stack Overflow Careers" does not exist any longer. That's what the combination of both employers and candidates on a completely separate site was called. Pretty much all questions here on Meta that *are* on-topic are the old questions about the old Careers product (I wouldn't recommend going around closing them all - old Careers questions do belong here).

We now have two separate sections related to jobs:

- Stack Overflow Jobs, which exists integrated into Stack Overflow. Questions about Jobs should be posted on Meta Stack Overflow as indicated.
- Stack Overflow Talent, which is the employer portal that still exists off-site. Questions about Talent don't really belong, well, anywhere. Generally the best option for an employer is to *reach out to their account manager* and field any concerns, complaints, or feedback directly to the team.

But why?

Well, trying to direct all employers to Meta Stack Overflow is kind of a huge slap in the face. Most employer accounts are run by some form of HR manager or employee - people who are less likely to have participated on Stack Overflow itself and thus less likely to have the needed 5 reputation to post there anyways.

As well, the employer side of Jobs is an actual paid feature, and part of that payment includes being able to talk to a live person to get your questions about that paid product answered right away. Any feedback, bug reports, new features requested through that channel can be directly handed off to the Jobs team from those conversations.

---

I've updated the help center article to reflect this information:

> **Have a question about Stack Overflow Jobs or Talent?**
>
> - Questions about [Stack Overflow Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) should be asked on [Meta Stack
>     Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com).
> - Questions about [Stack Overflow Talent](https://talent.stackoverflow.com) should be asked directly to
>     your account manager. If you don't know this contact person, please
>     [call our Talent sales
>     team](https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact).